# How to pack a JS library that contains images to be public accessible with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a simple library that export an `<Image name="cat" />` component. The component will use the `name` prop to figure out the correct `src` value for the underlining `<img />` tag.

However, I'm having trouble when bundling it with webpack (or maybe the problem itself is that I am trying to bundle it before publishing to npm). Here's some code to better paint a picture:

```
import cat from "../images/cat.png"
import dog from "../images/dog.png"

const images = { cat, dog }

const Image = ({ name }) => (
  <img src={images[name]} />
)
```

```
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      }]
    },
```

After I have run `webpack` on my library, the `dist/` directory will contain a directory with both `dog.png` and `cat.png`. The transpiled minified code will have string references to them. So I publish it to npm.

Now, here's the part that gets me. When I install the published package on my project and run it, and I consume the `<Image name="dog" />` component, the rendered `img` will still have the correct path (`/images/dog.png`), but `webpack-dev-server` hasn't realised it needs to process said file into the public directory. So in the browser, the URL resolves not on the image, but on the `index.html`.

Now, if instead I import the image directly to my project like `import dog from "my-library/images/dog.png`, then webpack correctly processes it.

I can think of a few things I'm doing wrong, but ultimately need some guidance:

1. I shouldn't be transpiling my library through webpack before publishing it in the first place, if I'm going to consume it through npm and webpack on the consumer project.
2. The right way of bundling assets on a library is such that the consumer project must import the asset (png) so that it webpack process it. Trying to abstract the image assets the way I'm attempting to with the `Image` component would never work.
3. My webpack configuration is fundamentally flawed and I am missing information on how to do asset loading.

How should I proceed?